# filtering rows using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file like this which is tab separated:

```
name    v1  v2  v3  v4
g1  4.5 2.3 2.1 0.2
g2  10  3   5   2.3
g3  7   2.5 2.8 3.9
```

Just showing you above a dummy file where I have 5 columns and 4 rows(including the header). I want to filter out the rows such that if every column in a particular row has value >= 2, then keep that row else remove it.
The output should look like this:

```
name    v1  v2  v3  v4
g2  10  3   5   2.3
g3  7   2.5 2.8 3.9
```

How can I do it using awk?

Comment: Did you mean to say *every* rather than *any*? because 4.5, 2.3 and 2.1 are all >=2

Comment: v4 has 0.2 as it's value, so that row should be filtered out

Comment: Sorry my bad, I changed the confusing part. It should be "every"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK awk doesn't have a way of doing this short of iterating over fields explicitly. For example:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i+0 < 2) next} 1' file
name    v1  v2  v3  v4
g2  10  3   5   2.3
g3  7   2.5 2.8 3.9
```

Comment: It doesn't hurt but you don't **need** the `+0` in this case since all the values being compared look like numbers and so awks comparing a strnum ($i) to a number (2) and so it'll already be a numeric comparison.

Answer (score 0):

steeldriver has already provided an awk solution. Here's a perl version (using an array slice rather than a for loop):

```
$ perl -lane 'print if ($.==1 || grep ($_ >= 2, @F) == $#F)' input.txt
name    v1  v2  v3  v4
g2  10  3   5   2.3
g3  7   2.5 2.8 3.9
```

This prints only the first (header) line and lines where all numeric fields have a value greater than or equal to 2.  (non-numeric fields like `g1` or `g2` will evaluate to `0`)

---

Note: perl's `grep()` function is similar in concept, but not exactly the same as the `grep` command-line program.

`grep(expression,array)` runs the expression in its first argument (e.g. `$_ >= 2`) against *every element of an array* (e.g. `@F`), and returns an array consisting of every element where the result was true.

In a scalar context (such as a numeric comparison against an integer), it returns the number of times the expression was true, instead of an array.  This is what we are doing here with `== $#F`, to test equivalence with `$#F` (the number of elements in array `@F`)

The expression can be a simple test as used in this example, or a code block containing any perl code.  It can also optionally modify each element. e.g. `@new = grep(s/foo/bar/g, @old)` would populate @new with all elements from @old which were successfully modified (i.e. thost that contained at least one "foo".  all of which were changed to "bar").  See `perldoc -f grep` for details.